# Make first level items in mmenu from <span> to hyperlink

Tags: html, mmenu

I make a menu with the mmenu plugin in my typo3 website. the Menu has only one level ! in the Mobile sight (Hamburger) they are all `<span>` and not clickable !!!

`<ul class="mm-listview">
    <li><span>First</span></li> 
    <li><span>second</span></li> 
  </ul>`

this is my main javascript

```
$("#my-menu").mmenu({

        "extensions": [
            "theme-topit",
            "fullscreen"
        ],
        "autoHeight": {
            "height": "highest"
        },
        "navbars": [
            {
                "position":"top",
                "height": 2,
                "content":[
                    "<div id='searchinMobileNav'></div>","close"
                ]
            },

            {
                "position": "bottom",
                "height": 2,
                "content": [
                    "<div id='socialLinksMobileNav'></div>"
                ]
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        classNames: {
            selected: 'cur'
        }
    }
);
```

What should I do to change the `<span>` to `<a href>`

Comment: Maybe try something using `replaceWith()` method. http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: Or, can't you just put a `<a href="…">Text</a>` element in the `li`s of the menu?

Comment: I don't know the mmenu JS lib and what HTML you need to provide from TYPO3, nut maybe your HTML is not correct. Menu items can be generated like `<li><a ...><span>text</span></a></li>` or like `<li><span><a ...>text</a></span></li>` (property `ATagBeforeWrap`). this could make the difference if the link is copied in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
In typo3 there is a lib.mobilenav.ts the (expALL) should be 1 otherwise the Parent could not be open !!!